# Who is this character in the video for "The Saga Begins" by Weird Al Yankovic?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, music-video, weird-al-yankovic

In the video for the Weird Al Yankovic song ["The Saga Begins"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_Begins) (1999), Weird Al is playing at a Mos Eisley-type cantina, where several aliens can be seen dancing alongside the regular *Star Wars* characters.

At 3:39 there is a character I think I have seen somewhere else, but I've never found any clue about him. Knowing that Weird Al likes to make external references in his videos, I'm almost sure this alien guy is not there by accident.

**Does anyone know who this is?**

Please take into account that the outfit is more extravagant than useful (nowadays alien spacesuits ornaments *at least* pretend to have some utility) and that this guy is actually **in black and white**. I suspect this is a cartoon character or mascot from the 50's or 60's or a secondary character in a very cartoonish B-Movie, since I've found nothing in classic sci-fi from this era featuring this guy as a main protagonist.

[image: Suspect dancing at the Obi-Al's Concert]

[image: The same guy showing a few more steps]

Comment: Yes, actually I think the two of them are husband and wife with that guy being the main character.

Comment: There's something Klingon about those collars, like what Chang and Gorkon wore in *Star Trek VI*.

Comment: I get a Farscape vibe from that image...

Comment: @HorusKol - It reminded me of Dune.

Comment: The tendrils that hangs from the collars make me think this is some humanoid-insect species. If this is faithful reference, I would rule out both Farscape and Star Wars since they often go the extra mile to not use humanoid aliens. That is more Star Trek way of doing things

Comment: For some reason, the neck pieces remind me of the Time Lords, but the actual costumes look significantly different.

Comment: This character has to be pre-1990, since I think I remember him from my childhood.

Comment: Then there's the collar and Snoopy cap of the [spacesuit](https://www.davelandweb.com/tomorrowland/images/spaceman/1957_KCOP_BW.jpg) from Disneyland's [Tomorrowland](https://www.davelandweb.com/tomorrowland/spaceman.html).

Comment: They remind me of the guy who stands next to Chancellor Valorum in episode 1. Thought not exactly like the alien of course being a spoof-looks like he's referencing that guy who calls for "order"

Comment: I've tried asking via Twitter. I will let you know if I get a response.